# python pyramid garbage collection

Tags: python, garbage-collection, pyramid

While investigating memory leak issue, saw these results. As I am using pyramid web framework what is the best way to cleanup these objects?

```
 types | # objects | total size
=================================================== | =========== | ============
 dict | 957482 | 560.44 MB
 unicode | 509861 | 158.82 MB
 tuple | 1169055 | 86.54 MB
 str | 317844 | 50.17 MB
 list | 335534 | 33.62 MB
 set | 19873 | 4.52 MB
 <class 'psycopg2.Column | 177121 | 18.92 MB
 <class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.PopulateDict | 18229 | 16.68 MB
 <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements._anonymous_label | 120168 | 15.64 MB
 <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.compiler._CompileLabel | 176992 | 13.50 MB
 <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BindParameter | 119670 | 7.30 MB
 <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseList | 90530 | 5.53 MB
 <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Grouping | 74269 | 4.53 MB
 psycopg2._psycopg.cursor | 18292 | 4.33 MB
 <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression | 67464 | 4.12 MB
```

Comment: Using the `del` statement?

Comment: You can force the process to perform a garbage collection [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html)

Comment: I had tried and gc.collect() still memory keeps on adding in every request. How to find out 
"dict | 957482 | 560.44 MB"
the dicts which are responsible for 504MB memory?

Comment: Your best bet would be figuring out why Python is holding on to any resources, do you have any circular references that make it difficult to garbage collect? Are you able to figure out where memory is being allocated and seeing if that memory is later cleared? There is not enough information here to provide a good answer, and it is unclear what exactly you are asking.